# twitter api count more than 100, using twitter search api

Tags: python-3.x, api, search, twitter

i want to search-tweet related 'data' and count more than 100

this is python grammer

```
from twython import Twython
twitter= Twython(app_key=APP_KEY,app_secret=APP_SECRET)
for status in twitter.search(q='"data"',count =10000)["statuses"]:
user =status["user"]["screen_name"].encode('utf-8')
text =status["text"]
data = "{0} {1} {2}".format(user ,text,'\n\n')
print(data)
f.writelines(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you're trying to do uses the Twitter API. Specifically the `GET search/tweets` endpoint.

In the docs for this endpoint:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

We can see that count has a maximum value of 100:

[image]

So even though you specify 10000, it only returns 100 because that's the max.

I've not tried either, but you can likely use the `until` or `max_id` parameters also mentioned in the docs to get more results/the next 100 results.

Keep in mind: "that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week" - the docs

Hope this helps!

Comment: If that answers your question - don't forget to mark as the Answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the field `next_token` of the response to get more tweets.

Refer to these articles:
https://lixinjack.com/how-to-collect-more-than-100-tweets-when-using-twitter-api-v2/
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/integrate/paginate

Answer (score 0):

The **max_id** parameter is the key and it is further explained here:

> To use max_id correctly, an application’s first request to a timeline
>   endpoint should only specify a count. When processing this and
>   subsequent responses, keep track of the lowest ID received. This ID
>   should be passed as the value of the max_id parameter for the next
>   request, which will only return Tweets with IDs lower than or equal to
>   the value of the max_id parameter.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines

In other words, using the lowest **id** retrieved from a search, you can access the older tweets. As mentioned by Tyler, the non-commercial version is limited to 7-day, but the commercial version can search up to 30 days.